# Cloud 9 running rails server, but not connected to http://localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning Learn Ruby on Rails: Book Two I have  set everything up in `Cloud9`, type in `rails server` and I get this output and the page for the app says its not running, I'm new to this not sure what I should see once the server is running

```
=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

[2016-03-28 05:35:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1

[2016-03-28 05:35:18] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]

[2016-03-28 05:35:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=22795 port=3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the server using following command:

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it

Comment: @chanm glad that it helped you !
You can accept this as answer if it has solved your problem. :)